# Why is the last line of the file printed twice when I scan every line of the file using fgets and print it until I reach the EOF?

Tags: c, file, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
void main(){

    FILE *g;
    int i;
    char str[100];

    g = fopen("graph_input.txt", "r");

    while(!feof(g)){
        fgets(str, 100, g);
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    fclose(g);
}
```

This code gives the following output:

```
7
2 4
1 3 4 6
2 6
1 2 6 5
4
4 2 3 7
6
6
```

The `graph_input.txt` file is:

```
7
2 4
1 3 4 6
2 6
1 2 6 5
4
4 2 3 7
6
```

**MY QUESTION**

Why is the output showing the last line twice (i.e. the number 6 is being printed twice)?

Comment: fgets reads up to newline, so eof hasn’t been triggered when the last line is returned. The next fgets fails (unnoticed as you aren’t checking the return value), and you print the existing contents of the buffer a second time.

Comment: Esha, who suggested using `while(!feof(g)){`?

Comment: I saw in a book in an example.

Comment: Time for a bonfire and a new book then.